# Adding image to ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a listview that shows a time schedule. I want to add an image to each row. How would I be able to do that?

This is the xml I am using:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the adapter:

```
ListView list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, times);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: use a custom adapter. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: Wow, that is a huge step forward.

Comment: In the adapters getView-method you can easily populate the items with images. Just inflate the  xml-file that holds the views and put images in the imageView-object. Inflate with LayoutInflater

Answer (score 0):

**Here i populated Listview with one ImageView and Three TextView using below layout file.
here when we have listview  with images then we download image one by one asyncronously in android.Then create bitmap from url and set it to imageview .so when you work with image then first read data from url byte by byte  and image have more bites that text so its take time to load in listview.**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="#444"
    android:padding="3dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvtitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvdate"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="title"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvdesc"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvtitle"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:text="desc"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="13dip" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvdate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:text="date"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="12dip" />
```

here we have row and there are three Textview and imageview.so in Adapter Class we inflate this row in getView() method.

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

Now we use Viewholder for add row in listview for smooth listview in android.

public static class ViewHolder {
  public TextView tvTitle, tvDesc, tvDate;
  private ImageView imgView;
 }

now create new object of ViewHolder for every row while view is null.otherwise set as a tag using setTag(ViewHolder).

ViewHolder holder;
if(view==null){
      holder = new ViewHolder();
      view.setTag(holder);
   }
else {
      holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
  }

now using viewHolder object you can refrenced your view from row.xml.

holder.tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvtitle);
holder.tvDesc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvdesc);
holder.tvDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvdate);
holder.imgView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);

we can set here value of each view of row.

holder.tvTitle.setText("title");
holder.tvDesc.setText("title"); 
holder.tvDate.setText("title"); 
holder.imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);

then return statement of getView method is view.
return view;

## For Mor Information You can Refer this link :

http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-image-listview.html